# how to print text within in div tag

Tags: jquery, css

i want print the text over div tag. here i have three arrays. x_array and y_array continas cooridantes of x and y values and txt_array contains text. based and x and y coordinates text will displayed with in the div tag. following code will displayed expected output but it will display only last array element. remaining will be erased. i want display all text based on x and y coordinates. pls... help me.

```
<script>
        var i=0;
       // var obj={"A","B","C","D"};
   $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#myimg").hover(function(){

  var x1=["50","100","150","200"];
  var y1=["50","100","150","200"];
  var txt1=["Text1","Text2","Text3","Text4"];
  var i=0;

  for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
      {

  var X=x1[i];
  var Y=y1[i];
  var txt=txt1[i];

      $("#myimg").append($("#test").offset({left:X,top:Y}));                    
      $("#test").html(txt);


  }

 });
 });
    </script>
```

[image: Following is the out put]

Answer (score 1):

IDs **must** be unique. Try using `classes` instead.

Even if multiple IDs were allowed, your use of `.html()` would overwrite the HTML of all `#test` elements. You'll need to dynamically create the element through the script:

```
  var test = $("<span class='test'></span>");
  test.html(txt);
  $("#myimg").append(test.offset({left:X,top:Y}));
```

Equally, if you have multiple `#myimg` elements, use classes for those, too.

Comment: The last line you wrote will change html for each element with class test.

Comment: Yes I'd only spotted that after I'd clicked to submit the answer, I've modified it now. :-)

Comment: @user1990992 check the modified answer.

Comment: thanq i got the out expected out put @James Donnely

Comment: how to clear all the text what ever display on hover event is fired when mouse leave the div tag

Comment: @user1990992 to do that you'd simply `$('.test').remove();`, assuming you wanted the elements completely removed. Hover accepts two functions (mouse over and mouse out): Update your hover function to use the mouse out function as well: `$('...').hover(function() { /* current code */ }, function() { $('.test').remove(); });`

Comment: u mean simply add function() { $('.test').remove(); }); to curren hover function   or any other

Comment: ya its working again small question. i have multiple images/div and each images/div have some text. how can i print corresponding text to image/div tag   please see the output here http://i.stack.imgur.com/9oizU.png @James Donnelly

Comment: I think that would be better as a separate question as it falls outside the scope of this one.